# Failed to allocate memory from loading jpg files - Android studio Erro

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a function in my app that adds offline pictures that are stored inside the app's memory to a listview.
The code is extremely simple as you can see:

```
if(FirstTag != null) {
        if (FirstTag.equals("care"))
            imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.care));
        else if (FirstTag.equals("holidays"))
            imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.holidays));
        else if (FirstTag.equals("Thing Different"))
            imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thinkdifferent2));
        else if (FirstTag.equals("Fun Activities"))
            imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fun));
        else if (FirstTag.equals("מערך חברות")) }
```

it simply checks a value in a json object and put a picture in the listview by this value, of course there are 20 values and not 5, but I didn't think I should Include all...
All the pictures are compressed, and when I don't load many of them the app doesn't crash.
But when I try to launch the app with a picture per each item in the listview, everything seems to work perfectly fine, and then when you scroll down the app lags and in a second it crashes with the following error:

> 9-30 18:35:18.299 7859-7859/com.example.negev.peulibraryv201 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.negev.peulibraryv201, PID: 7859
>                                                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 681099532 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 261MB until OOM
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1179)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:770)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1611)
>                                                                                       at com.example.negev.peulibraryv201.GamesLibraryAdapter.getView(GamesLibraryAdapter.java:70)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3238)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2147)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:767)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:731)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:8292)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:2065)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:7719)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:635)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

I already added those line to my manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
```

and it didn't work, wht do you think I can do?
Thank you!

Comment: What size are the images? At the time of loading them into the listview (where you actually would need a thumbnail), you can scale the image so it doesn't occupy more memory than necessary. If you are using the viewholder pattern in the listview, you could even dispose the old bitmap to help Android clean it up quicker.

Comment: actually each image is in a different size, I am now trying the same thing with all of them scaled to 720p width. do you think it will help?

Comment: Totally agree with @Juan, you even can look into some image libraries to see if they can solve runtime scaling for you. See [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html).

Comment: Libraries aren't going to help you here.  You're trying to open a 680 MB image!  That's way, way, way too big.  There is no way you'll ever make that work.  You need to make the image reasonable sized.  Remember that each image takes 4*width*height bytes in memory, and that you're limited to about 100MB max of Java heap memory-  less on many devices.

Comment: but the pictures' total size is 2mb, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is load the data dynamically as it becomes visible on the screen.
Since this is hard work Google already did it for you.
You need to use an ArrayAdapter with the list view and let Andriod ask you for more data when it is needed.
Its too much code to explain in detail but have a look at [this Goolge I/O video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).
There are many tutorials on the web that explains how to do that in detail.
Have a look [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView).